# How do you create a Smart Group with participants from multiple events

Tags: civievent, smartgroups

I'm trying to create a smart group for all registered users in any 2019 event. There are 5 events I'm trying to pull participants from into a smart group.

The process I am trying to use is:

1. Click "Events" -> Click "Find Participants"
2. Add the 5 events in the Event Name field
3. Choose the Participant Status of "Registered"
4. Click "Search"
5. Click the "All 214 records" radio button (214 Results are found)
6. Click the "Actions" drop down and select "Group - create smart group"
7. Enter a name in the "Name" field
8. Enter a description in the "Description" field
9. Click "Save Smart Group"

The result is an error message that returns:
`72,74,76,80,75 is not of the type Int`

The error itself is not that confusing to me. A comma separated list of event ID's is obviously not an Int.

However, I am not sure how to get around this issue.

How do you create a smart group containing participants from multiple events?

Comment: I was able to replicate at dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and I have opened an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that going through almost the same process under "Search" -> "Advanced Search"
allows you to create a smart group of people from multiple events.

Comment: It was possible for Advanced Search since 5.12 thanks to https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/469